# Passing Unpacked Array of Packed Array as task arguments

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
task xyz(output op, output bit [width-1:0] write_data []);
```

I have my task `xyz` definiton in an interface. I want to call this task from my testbench.sv.

How should I call it? I am trying to call it in this manner, but I am getting an error:

```
xyz(1'b0, bit[width-1:0] write_data [])
```

What's the correct way of passing an unpacked array of packed array as task arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 types of errors in your task call line.

You should not use the variable type (`bit`) or any dimensions.  These are only used in the task definition.  Instead of passing:

```
bit[width-1:0] write_data []
```

simply pass the variable name:

```
write_data
```

You must not connect a constant (`1'b0`) to the `op` output.

Here is a complete code example which has no compile errors:

```
module tb;
  parameter width = 4;
  bit [width-1:0] write_data [];
  bit op;
  
  task xyz(output op, output bit [width-1:0] write_data []);
  endtask
  
  initial begin
    xyz(op, write_data);
  end
endmodule
```

Here is the code on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/B9RZ).